# C# How to use a generic method parameter that is a generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods, parameters

So I have the following code:

```
public Dictionary<int, Class1<Class2>> someDictionary;

public T DoThings<T, U>(int id) where T : Class1<U>, new() where U : Class2, new()
{
    T something = null;
    if (!someDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        something = new T();
        someDictionary.Add(id, something);
    }
    return something;
}
```

And I am getting this error while trying to add to someDictionary:

> Argument 2: Cannot convert from 'T' to 'Class1 < Class2 >'

Any help as to how to solve this, if it even can be solved would be greatly appriciated, thanks.

Luke.

Comment: Why not just have `where T : Class1<Class2>, new()`?

Comment: Yep, I just found that it would work like that, thanks for the reply though. I'm pretty sure what I was trying to do was somewhat redundant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the generic class.

```
public class ShouldOneClass<T,U> where T : Class1<U>, new() 
                                 where U : Class2, new()
{
    public Dictionary<int, T> someDictionary;
}
```

But if you don't want use generic class , replace generics type with interface.